# Initialize N Class Objects; VBA

Tags: excel, vba, class, loops, object

Working in Excel VBA, and I am trying to initialize an array of several objects of the class "CUserType", but I am having some trouble. I tried doing this in a loop, like this:

```
For count = 1 To size
    Dim myArray(count)   As CUserType
Next
```

However, it looks like VBA wants the array index to be a constant integer.

Now I am trying to do it with a separate function, like this:

```
Sub ititUsers(num As Integer)

Dim myArray()           As CUserType
Redim myArray(1 to num)

If num = 1 Then
    Dim myArray(1)      As CUserType
ElseIf num = 2 Then
    Dim myArray(1)      As New CUserType
    Dim myArray(2)      As New CUserType
ElseIf num = 3 Then
    Dim myArray(1)      As New CUserType
    Dim myArray(2)      As New CUserType
    Dim myArray(3)      As New CUserType
.
.
.
End Sub
```

But of course this is both tedious and wasteful. I am new to this, so I know I am probably missing something. Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your line `Dim myArray(count)   As CUserType` is already setting all elements of the array as CUserType.  If you just need to initialize it, then do a For Loop:

```
Sub ititUsers(num As Integer)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim myArray() As CUserType
    Redim myArray(1 to num)

    For i = 1 to num
        Set myArray(i) = New CUserType
    Next i

End Sub
```